# Module position defined in template's manifest.xml is not shown in the joomla backend

Tags: templates, module, position, joomla2.5

I am almost new to joomla. I am working in Ubuntu on Joomla v2.5. I created a custom template in which I created a background image, menu and logo. It is a small template and has below code if I view it in browser.

```
    <div class="main-menu">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li>Groceries</li>
        <li>Exercise</li>
        <li>Destress</li>
        <li>Ailments</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Then I modified it for installing into joomla and it looked as below

```
    <div class="main-menu">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menuarea" />
    </div>
```

Also, In the **manifest.xml** I have defined the position as below

```
  <positions>
    <position>menuarea</position>
  </positions>
```

After the installation was successful, I changed the template. It was working and now it was the time to define main menu.
So, I tried to edit the position of mainmenu in the backend and in I could not find the position **menuarea**. Please suggest where I am going wrong.
Extra Information - I installed the fresh joomla directory and only modification I did was installed this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change in module option Position. For this open Exstensions->Module Manager->Your_Module and type "menuarea" for Position and save.